# Get solutions of an equation given its output

Tags: linear-algebra

Lets assume I have a function $f(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ that takes $x_1, x_2, x_3$ as inputs. For the sake of simplicity, lets assume that this $f(x)$ is a linear equation.

My question is- if I decide that the output of my function has to be an arbitrary value- $v$, can I generate all or a fixed number of the possible solutions or combinations of values that when passed to $f$ will generate $v$?

If yes, how do I achieve this?

Comment: What you're describing there is just the problem of solving a linear equation.

Comment: @ClockSlave Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Since you assume that $f(x)$ is linear, it takes the form $a_0 + a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3$. Let $v'=v-a_0.$ If $\mathbf{a}=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$, you have to find all $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\mathbf{a}.\mathbf{x}=v'$.

To find $\mathbf{x}$, we can do a coordinate transformation so that $\mathbf{a}$ is aligned with the $x$-axis and then $\mathbf{x}$ is any vector whose $x$ component equals $v'$ in the new system. Use inverse coordinate transformation to find $\mathbf{x}$ in the original coordinate system.

I'm sorry for the partial answer but I've forgotten how to do these steps. Maybe someone else can elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

The equation $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=v$ describes a surface in the space $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. This is called the implicit equation of the surface. If you vary $v$, you will get another surface "nested" in the first. For instance, $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=v$ gives you a family of concentric spheres of radius $\sqrt v$.

In the case of a linear transform, these surfaces are parallel planes.

You can obtain all solutions of

$$ax_1+bx_2+cx_3=v$$ by setting two coordinates arbitrarily and computing the third one, e.g.

$$x_3=\frac{v-ax_1-bx_2}c.$$

Comment: Why are we assuming that $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ are scalars? It is not stated in the OP.

Comment: @gimusi: Why would we be assuming that $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ are vectors ? It is not stated in the OP.

Comment: For example because the vector case is more general and the scalar case can be treated as a particular case.

Comment: @gimusi: then in your answer make sure to use matrices to express the linear function as this is more general and the dot product case can be treated as a particular case. Don't forget to specify that $A_1$ must be invertible.

Comment: I don't understand this last comment, anyway I think that the answers given are sufficent for the OP. Bye

Answer (score -1):

Yes, for a linear function it is always possible to reconstruct $x$ from $v$ given that $v$ is a solution.

In general, for $f:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R^m}$ to do that we simply need to solve the linear system $Ax=v$, where $A$ is the matrix representation of $f$ for a given basis.

For the particular case of $f:\mathbb{R^3}\to\mathbb{R}$, we have that $x_1$,$x_2$ and $x_3$ scalars and we need to solve

$$a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3=v$$

which has infinitely many solutions, that is setting $x_2=s$ and $x_3=t$

$$x_1=\frac{v-a_2s-a_3 t}{a_1}$$